# usage of definite article "the"

Tags: definite-article

Can anyone please tell me if I can leave the word ***the*** out in the following sentences? Can any teacher on anyone who has good grasp on the language please explain it to me?

1- Nothing is impossible in this world. Everything can be achieved. It depends on ***the*** mindsets of people how they cope with tough situations in their lives and how hard they work to reach their goals.

2- ***The*** teeth of tigers are very sharp.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In both examples, you could remove ***the*** by restructuring to use possessives.

1. *It depends on people's mindsets how they cope...*
2. *Tigers' teeth are very sharp.*

As for just removing ***the*** from the original sentence:

1. It would still make grammatical sense, but might not flow as well.
2. A native English speaker wouldn't say *teeth of tigers*. You'd either need *the*, or use a possessive as above.